# linux kernel build for Ti wifi driver

Tags: github, build, linux-kernel, arm, xilinx

Actually i am trying to integrate the Wilink8 wifi module from TI with the   Zedboard and i found some scripts at http://zedboard.org/product/wilink-8-adaptor website. But these scripts are for microzed board. Here i am sharing the script:-

git clone git://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx

git checkout -b xilinx-v2014.2.01 xilinx-v2014.2.01

http://downloads.architechboards.com/deposit/microZed_wilink8.config -O .config

make LOADADDR=0x8000 uImage

make modules

So you can see that in the above script line number 3 i have one .config file.That is why i did not run the step make defconfig and when i run the make modules it started asking a lot of options with "yes" and "no"  to me.As i am naive to linux development environment so i do not for what options should i put yes and no. But from reading various posts on stackoverflow i came to know that first we should run make defconfig and then we should run make module option.
So can you please suggest me following:-

1- In the above script, since i am having the .config file already, so if i run make olddefconfig first and then make module then it should be fine and in that case it should not ask me the options. Am i right???

2- So if above thing is not possible, then can you please suggest me Which version should i clone from the github website so that it can give the defconfig file for me the Zedboard with Wilink8 wifi module from TI.

Regards
ADITYA

Comment: Just run `make olddefconfig`. This should select the .config as default configuration for kernel. `make help` for more options. A quick note, If you have plan to use configuration of different board, then you should be careful in checking the SoC and platform drivers accordingly. There is a high possibility that the board will not boot if there is mismatch in the board/SoC hardware.

Comment: For the specific WiFi driver, check the KConfig file in the source tree to enable the same.